# How do I get the value of weight and bias from auto-encoder program

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I ran [mnist_ae1.py](https://gist.github.com/tomokishii/7ddde510edb1c4273438ba0663b26fc6#file-mnist_ae1-py)(very simple model of auto-encoder), and want to get value of `w_enc` and `b_enc`.
So, I added some process as below.

```
# Train
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    print('Training...')
    for i in range(10001):
        batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(128)
        train_step.run({x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

        if i % 1000 == 0:
            train_loss = loss.eval({x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
            print('  step, loss = %6d: %6.3f' % (i, train_loss))

    # generate decoded image with test data
    test_fd = {x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}
    decoded_imgs = decoded.eval(test_fd)
    print('loss (test) = ', loss.eval(test_fd))

    # add
    w_enc_array, b_enc_array = train_step.run([w_enc, b_enc], {x: mnist.test.images})
    print("w_enc :", w_enc_array)
    print("b_enc :", b_enc_array)

    weight_result = np.append(w_enc_array, 0)
    weight_result = np.append(weight_result, b_enc)
    np.savetxt("weight_result.csv", weight_result, delimiter=",")
```

However, the following error was thrown.

```
w_enc_array, b_enc_array = train_step.run([w_enc, b_enc], {x: mnist.test.images})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1449, in run
    _run_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3664, in _run_using_default_session
    if session.graph is not graph:
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'graph'
```

How do I get and save the value of `w_enc` and `b_enc`?

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to [Operation.run](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Operation#run) which you call in the `train_step.run` line is the session. By passing a dictionary there you confuse the runtime into treating that dictionary as a session. Try doing `feed_dict={x...}` instead.